# How to display wordpress page from title, from php $_GET value

Tags: wordpress, get

I'm trying to create an automated page with Wordpress and the php g php $_GET value.
I have a navigation bar that creates links like this: photobooks.php?year=2012
I would then like wordpress to find the page with that title and display it.
I have found this code, but it doesn't seem to work properly.

```
<?php
$year = $_GET['year'];
$page_title = $year;
get_page_by_title( $page_title, $post_type );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

see first of all you are requesting the year, and do you have a page that has the same name of the year!!

I think you are looking for some thing like the below code

```
$args = array(
    'cat'      => 22,
    'year'     => $current_year,
    'monthnum' => $current_month,
    'order'    => 'ASC'
);
query_posts( $args );
```

It displays posts of a particular year!!

Comment: No, I'm combining code that's outside of wordpress, so I'm not looking for posts. I want it to get the year from the url and then search for a page with that title as it's name and then display it.